# Need help with setting up SSL

Tags: iis, xhtml, ssl, https

Newbie IIS question:

I want to setup HTTPS access for my XHTML page (not asp.net) hosted on my IIS 6.0 server. So far I have done the following:

In IIS Manager, for the particular folder, the following are set:

- Require secure channel (SSL)
- Require 128 bit encryption
- Ignore client certificates

However when I try to access the page from IE 8.0 there is the following error:
"Internet explorer cannot display the page".

The options for using SSL and TSL are ON in the IE settings. Same error with Firefox also.

**Apart from the above is there any else I should setup on the IIS server?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/299875) are the official instructions for setting up SSL in IIS. You can find directions [here](http://codeforeternity.com/blogs/technology/archive/2008/02/15/creating-self-signed-ssl-certificates-on-iis-6-0-and-windows-server-2003.aspx) for creating a self signed certificate if that is the route you want to take.

Answer (score 3):

Have you generated a [self-signed server certificat](http://www.somacon.com/p42.php)e?

Comment: Yes, you didn't mention generating or installing the certificate for the server.